# Open VBA file excel with parameters by Excel Interop

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I have a program that Executes VBA excel file with parameters like

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

object _ExcelPathLocation = Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\excel.exe", "Path", null);

 if (sugbdika.Equals("פולס"))
            {
                startInfo.FileName = FileName;
                startInfo.Arguments = Arguments;
            }
            else
            {
                startInfo.FileName = $"{_ExcelPathLocationStr}EXCEL.EXE ";
                startInfo.Arguments = "/x " + FileName + " " + Arguments;
            }
 Process p = Process.Start(startInfo);
```

The command line look like that :

startInfo.FileName => `C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Root\\Office16\\EXCEL.EXE`
startInfo.Arguments=> `/x \\\\FILES\\~Departments\\tadWeb_reports\\Milenium.xltm  /t/LE-15576/A/4/3.0/3.0`
Actualy I want to open the  `\\FILES\~Departments\tadWeb_reports\Milenium.xltm` file with this parameters string like `/t/LE-15576/A/4/3.0/3.0`

How can I do it by Excel Interop?

I have to try do

```
object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oExcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

            oExcel.Visible = true;

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks oBooks = oExcel.Workbooks;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook oBook = null;

            oBook = oBooks.Open($"{startInfo.Arguments}", oMissing, oMissing,
                oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing,
                oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing);
```

To use open on the next line : `\\\\FILES\\~Departments\\tadWeb_reports\\Milenium.xltm  /t/LE-15576/A/4/3.0/3.0`

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right avenue - the [Workbooks.Open](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Workbooks.Open) method opens a workbook. Most probably you will have to copy the file locally and then open it.

If you need to get command line arguments you can use the [Environment.GetCommandLineArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getcommandlineargs?view=netcore-3.1) method which returns a string array containing the command-line arguments for the current process.

```
Application.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Test\YourWorkbook.xlsx");
```

See [How to: Programmatically open workbooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-programmatically-open-workbooks?view=vs-2019) for more information.

Comment: But I want to pass  the command line to the xlsx file and get it on the vba. And to pass it by c# to it.     To pass this line to the vba file as is  '/t/LE-15576/A/4/3.0/3.0'